# Remote Audio Over IP

Tags: audio, networking, ethernet

I have five audio sources at a remote location. I want to be able to virtualize them over Ethernet and then be able to listen to them remotely over a LAN.

In an ideal world, I picture a piece of equipment which accept audio inputs and has an Ethernet connection.

Then I'd need to have a driver on the remote PC end which could interface to that piece of hardware. It would allow me to select which audio stream I want to listen to and would make it available to the Operating System as a virtual sound card. This is essential so that I can continue using my existing audio software (which is expecting live input from a mic or line-in).

Comment: It looks like Audinate makes a product called Dante Virtual Soundcard which does exactly what I need. Audinate sells the software but requires Dante-enabled hardware. My issue now is that I have NO IDEA what piece of hardware to buy for my purpose.